# Accessing C# Anonymous Type Objects

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

How do i access objects of an anonymous type outside the scope where its declared?

for e.g.

```
void FuncB()
{
var obj = FuncA();
Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);
}

??? FuncA()
{
var a = (from e in DB.Entities
where e.Id == 1
select new {Id = e.Id, Name = e.Name}).FirstOrDefault();

return a;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to return Anonymous Type from method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329672/is-there-a-way-to-return-anonymous-type-from-method)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As the other answers have stated, **you really shouldn't do this**. But, if you insist, then there's a nasty hack known as "cast by example" which will allow you to do it. The technique is mentioned in a couple of articles, [here](http://tomasp.net/blog/cannot-return-anonymous-type-from-method.aspx) and [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/01/09/horrible-grotty-hack-returning-an-anonymous-type-instance.aspx).

```
public void FuncB()
{
    var example = new { Id = 0, Name = string.Empty };

    var obj = CastByExample(FuncA(), example);
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);
}

private object FuncA()
{
    var a = from e in DB.Entities
            where e.Id == 1
            select new { Id = e.Id, Name = e.Name };

    return a.FirstOrDefault();
}

private T CastByExample<T>(object target, T example)
{
    return (T)target;
}
```

(I can't take the credit for this hack, although [the author of one of those articles says that he doesn't want to be associated with it either](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:x_rICZ2nnxUJ:https://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2009/01/09/horrible-grotty-hack-returning-an-anonymous-type-instance/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us). His name might be familiar.)

Comment: Beaten by 8 seconds! I've deleted mine (no benefit in duplicating it). But to stress:: ***do not do this*** ;-p

Comment: So you've accepted this as your preferred answer. Although it's an interesting technique, I strongly recommend against using it in any important/production code!

Comment: Ya. Good to know that this can be done. Is really evil though but so am I. muhahhhhahahaaaa.

Comment: Thanks for this, I didn't use it :)) I ended up just using immutable structs.

Comment: There **are** valid reasons for wanting to do this.  See https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/542278/ability-to-return-strongly-typed-anonymous-classes#

Comment: This hack does have a specific caveat that it won't work across assembly boundaries. This is because the compiler generates the types based on the signature once per assembly so if you use `var example = new { Id = 0, Name = string.Empty };` in a different assembly than `FuncA()` the types won't match.

Comment: @LukeH, one link is "dead", it moved to [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/01/09/horrible-grotty-hack-returning-an-anonymous-type-instance/)

Answer (score 7):

You can't return an anonymous type from a function.

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx):

> To pass an anonymous type, or a collection that contains anonymous types, outside a method boundary, you must first cast the type to object. However, this defeats the strong typing of the anonymous type. If you must store your query results or pass them outside the method boundary, consider using an ordinary named struct or class instead of an anonymous type.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .NET 4.0, you can use Tuples for this, you'd return a `Tuple<int, string>`.  You can implement your own Tuples for 2.0/3.5, and actually other people already have, so you should be able to do that if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous type is just a compiler-generated class, and the compiler is not willing to tell you the name of the class itself. Therefore, there's no way you can return an instance of this class from a function other than returning a reference to an `object`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think the answer is: Don't use an anonymous type outside the scope where its declared. In this case create a simple type.

Answer (score 0):

would create a class for this case:

```
public class LISTFUNCA   
{                         
    public int identificacion;  
    public string nombre;      
}
```

then:

```
public List<LISTFUNCA> FuncA()   
{                                          
    var lista = (from e in DB.Entities where e.Id == 1                        
                select new { identificacion = e.Id, nombre = e.Name})
                .FirstOrDefault();  
    return lista.ToList(); 
}
```

Comment: Please review your code; I reformatted it, but I believe it isn't correct.  Also, please read the [faq] for details about how to format your code correctly.  And, when you post something, and it looks awful, don't forget you can [edit your post to fix it.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2509405/edit)

Answer (score 0):

The open source framework [Impromptu-Interface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) will allow you to duck cast an anonymous object to an interface. It has the advantage of being less hacky because it will work as expected across assembly boundaries. It accomplishes this using a lightweight proxy and the dlr.