# TypeDescriptor.CreateProperty doesn't add a property

Tags: c#, data-binding, typedescriptor, system.componentmodel

I am trying to add a property to a type using TypeDescriptor.CreateProperty in order to display an additional property in a property grid, however this new property is not added and when I call TypeDescriptor.GetProperties on that type to inspect the properties, this property does not exist.

It there something I might be missing or overlooking? This is a basic and simple scenario as far as I remember.

Here is the call:
TypeDescriptor.CreateProperty(typeof (MovieMenuItem), "ExternalMediaLocation", typeof (string), null);

Comment: How about posting an example of the code that's not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CreateProperty` just gives you back a reflection-based `PropertyDescriptor` for the type in question (it isn't `AddProperty`, for example). What is the scenario here? If you just need to display extra data in `DataGridView`, the simplest option is simply to add an extra unbound column to the grid.

You *can* extend types at runtime, but for lists you have two main options:

- `ITypedList` (if each instance of the list can have different columns) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882214/data-binding-dynamic-data/882246#882246)
- `TypeDescriptionProvider` - allows you to add custom properties per-type (ultimately boils down to writing a `PropertyDescriptor`, just like the first example - but different hooks)

The full rules of how list-based metadata is fetched are in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927383/c-grid-datasource-polymorphism/954715#954715)

Comment: I want to add it to an object that I edit using a PropertyGrid control

Comment: Long time since the last time I "heavily" used component model... the type description provider is the missing link. Thanks!