# Is there a way to return Anonymous Type from method?

Tags: c#, .net, anonymous-types

I know I can't write a method like:

```
public var MyMethod()
{
   return new{ Property1 = "test", Property2="test"};
}
```

I can do it otherwise:

```
public object MyMethod()
{
   return new{ Property1 = "test", Property2="test"}
}
```

but I don't want to do the second option because, if I do so, I will have to use reflection.

---

Why I want to do that:

Today i have a method inside my aspx page that returns a datatable as result and I **cannot change it**, I was trying to convert this DataTable to an Anonymous method with the properties that I want to work with. I didn't want to create a class only to do that and as I will need to perform the same query more than one time, I Thought to create a method that returns an anonymous type would be a good ideia.

Comment: What would you use it for? How have you come to the conclusion that you would want to do something like that?

Comment: @Guffa, I have a method inside my aspx page that returns a datatable as result, I was trying to convert this datatable to an anonymous method with the properties that I want to work with. I didnt want to create a class only to do that and as I will need to perform the same query more than one time, I throught to create a method that returns an anonymous method would be a good ideia.

Comment: @Cleiton - it'll take much less effort to create a class to contain the data. I've come to realize that just because I can use anonymous types to manipulate data easily, it doesn't mean that I should stop creating classes to define those types when I need to pass them from one layer to another.

Comment: @Guffa: sometimes its convenient to return more than one value or a collection of related values from a function. Most languages provide tuples for ad-hoc, on-the-fly collections, but C# 3.5 doesn't support that functionality yet. The only C# alternatives are: creating a series of out-parameters, wrapping up ad-hoc objects in a class, or returning an object[].

Comment: Don't forget that, as of C# 3.0, you can declare a type with very little typing. Example: `public class NonAnonymousType { public int Foo { get; set; } public string Bar { get; set; } }` (please pardon the formatting)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return anonymous type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/return-anonymous-type)

Comment: Sort of an answer, given some constraints, can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58560612/286406

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Returning it as a `System.Object` is the *only* way to return an anonymous type from a method.  Unfortunately there is no other way to do this since anonymous types were designed specifically to prevent their use in this way.

There are some tricks that you can do to in conjunction with returning an `Object` that allow you to get close.  If you are interested in this workaround please read [Can't return anonymous type from method? Really?](http://tomasp.net/blog/cannot-return-anonymous-type-from-method.aspx).

*Disclaimer:* Even though the article I linked does show a workaround that doesn't mean it is a good idea to do it.  I would strongly discourage you using this approach when creating a regular type would be safer and easier to understand.

Comment: It should be noted that this is not a recommended idea. Intellisense will no longer recognize the strongly typed properties of the anonymous type (Property1 and Property2 from your example). Actually, you can use reflection to get at the properties, but you may as well be hitting your thumb with hammer for all the work you're putting into it, and not to mention you just took something that was supposed to make your life easier, but in fact made it harder.

Comment: +1 couldn't have said it better myself. Yes, it can be done, but that doesn't mean its a good idea.

Comment: You can return a "dynamic" as well, which I guess could be argued is a System.Object in disguise.

Answer (score 36):

As alternative, starting C# 7 we can use [ValueTuple](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/). A little example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41084411/whats-the-difference-between-system-valuetuple-and-system-tuple):

```
public (int sum, int count) DoStuff(IEnumerable<int> values) 
{
    var res = (sum: 0, count: 0);
    foreach (var value in values) { res.sum += value; res.count++; }
    return res;
}
```

And on the receiving end:

```
var result = DoStuff(Enumerable.Range(0, 10));
Console.WriteLine($"Sum: {result.Sum}, Count: {result.Count}");
```

Or:

```
var (sum, count) = DoStuff(Enumerable.Range(0, 10));
Console.WriteLine($"Sum: {sum}, Count: {count}");
```

Answer (score 28):

Alternatively, you can use the Tuple class in .NET 4.0 and higher:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Tuple<string, string> Create()
{
return Tuple.Create("test1", "test2");
}
```

then you can access the properties like this:

```
var result = Create();
result.Item1;
result.Item2;
```

Comment: Funny. I came here looking for an alternative to using tuples as return types.

Answer (score 21):

```
public object MyMethod() 
{
    return new
    {
         Property1 = "test",
        Property2 = "test"
     };
}

static void Main(..)
{
    dynamic o = MyMethod();  
    var p1 = o.Property1;
    var p2 = o.Property2;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

The easiest solution is to create a class, shove the values into the property, and then return it. If anonymous types are making your life harder then you're not using them correctly.

Answer (score 13):

Notwithstanding the warnings about whether this is a good idea or not... A `dynamic` seems to work just fine for a private method.

```
void Main()
{
    var result = MyMethod();
    Console.WriteLine($"Result: {result.Property1}, {result.Property2}");
}

public dynamic MyMethod()
{
    return new { Property1 = "test1", Property2 = "test2" };
}
```

You can run this example in [LinqPad.](http://www.linqpad.net/) It will output:

> Result: test1, test2

Comment: I think it's not the best, since dynamic will build into every data type, including object, so you would be better of with object, with less overhead.

Answer (score 4):

No, anonymous types cannot exist outside of the context in which they are created, and as a result cannot be used as a method return type. You can return the instance as an `object`, but it's a much better idea to explicitly create your own container type for this purpose.

Answer (score 4):

I think Andrew Hare is right, you'd have to just return "object."  For an editorial comment, I feel like dealing with raw objects in OO code can be a "code smell."  There are cases where it's the right thing to do, but most of the time, you'd be better off defining an interface to return, or using some sort of base class type, if you're going to be returning related types.

Comment: Using objects in OO code is a smell, what have we come to.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no support for expanding the scope of the anonymous class outside the method. Outside of the method the class is truly anonymous, and reflection is the only way to access it's members.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, you really aren't supposed to do that.  You can hack around it with reflection or by making a generic helper method to return the type for you, but doing so is really working against the language.  Just declare the type so it's clear what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

You could also invert your control flow if possible:

```
    public abstract class SafeAnon<TContext>
    {
        public static Anon<T> Create<T>(Func<T> anonFactory)
        {
            return new Anon<T>(anonFactory());
        }

        public abstract void Fire(TContext context);
        public class Anon<T> : SafeAnon<TContext>
        {
            private readonly T _out;

            public delegate void Delayed(TContext context, T anon);

            public Anon(T @out)
            {
                _out = @out;
            }

            public event Delayed UseMe;
            public override void Fire(TContext context)
            {
                UseMe?.Invoke(context, _out);
            }
        }
    }

    public static SafeAnon<SomeContext> Test()
    {
        var sa = SafeAnon<SomeContext>.Create(() => new { AnonStuff = "asdf123" });

        sa.UseMe += (ctx, anon) =>
        {
            ctx.Stuff.Add(anon.AnonStuff);
        };

        return sa;
    }

    public class SomeContext
    {
        public List<string> Stuff = new List<string>();
    }
```

and then later somwhere else:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        var anonWithoutContext = Test();

        var nowTheresMyContext = new SomeContext();
        anonWithoutContext.Fire(nowTheresMyContext);

        Console.WriteLine(nowTheresMyContext.Stuff[0]);

    }
```