# How to use anonymous type returned from a method

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a simple database that I use, with an EF data model to work with.

My tables looks like this:

**customers table**

- CustomerId
- CustomerName

**Orders table**

- OrderId
- CustomerID FK
- OrderDate

I'm using a helper class to query my model and in this class I have the following query:

```
public static List<object> GetCustomerOrdersCount()
{
    using (OrdersDbEntities context = new OrdersDbEntities())
    {
        return context.Customers.Select(
            c => new
            {
                CustId = c.CustomerId,
                CustName = c.CustomerName,
                OrdersCount = c.Orders.Count
            }).ToList<object>();
    }
}
```

The only return type I could use with this method is a `List<object>`

And finally my question is: how do I use the data received from this query?

The only way I can read the values is by reflection:

```
List<object> custs = Dal.GetCustomerOrdersCount();

foreach (var customer in custs)
{
   var properties = customer.GetType().GetProperties();

   foreach (var data in properties)
   {
      var value = data.GetValue(custs[0], null);
   }
}
```

I wonder if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: Why are you using object and not Customer?  I assume that context.Customers is a DbSet for Customer?

Comment: this is the error i get when trying to return List<Customers>:System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.ToList<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Please post the code for OrdersDbEntities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that I see is that you're selecting an anonymous type, can't you do:

```
public static List<object> GetCustomerOrdersCount()
{
        using (OrdersDbEntities context = new OrdersDbEntities())
        {
            return context.Customers.Select().ToList<Customer>();
        }
}
```

That would return your complete `Customer` entity, rather than an anonymous type that contains only specific members.

**EDIT**

If the underlying problem, in regards to our conversation about lazy loading, is that you want a count of the number of orders for a given customer, without actually loading the orders, then I would do something like this:

```
public class CustomerWithOrderCount
{
    public CustomerWithOrderCount(Customer c, int OrderCount) 
    { 
        Customer = c; 
        this.OrderCount = OrderCount;
    }
    public Customer { get; set; }
    public int OrderCount { get; set; }
}

public static List<object> GetCustomerOrdersCount()
{
        using (OrdersDbEntities context = new OrdersDbEntities())
        {
            return context.Customers.Select(
                c => new CustomerWithOrderCount(c, c.Orders.Count())
                             .ToList();
        }
}
```

Comment: this is the error i get when trying to do what you suggest:The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection. i guess i can do something like: return context.Customers.Include("Orders").ToList<Customers>(); but this will bring up a lot of unnecessary data...

Comment: Yes, you're probably trying to do lazy loading.  If you want to do that you need to keep the context that was used to load the entity alive so the entity can use the context to fetch data from the database.  Otherwise using `.Include()` or `.LoadProperty()` to eaglerly load the extra data is the best way to go.

Comment: or i could keep using the reflection :) i will try to look up this lazy loading thing you mentioned

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MiniCustomerDto
{
  public int CustomerId{get;set;}
  public String CustomerName{get;set;}
  public int OrdersCount{get;set;}
}

public static List<MiniCustomerDto> GetCustomerOrdersCount()
{
        using (OrdersDbEntities context = new OrdersDbEntities())
        {
            return context.Customers.Select(c => new MiniCustomerDto
            {
                CustId = c.CustomerId,
                CustName = c.CustomerName,
                OrdersCount = c.Orders.Count
            }).ToList();
        }
}
```

you have to use class you can't create a method that return anonymous type
abd this is the best practice check,
[Is there a way to return Anonymous Type from method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329672/is-there-a-way-to-return-anonymous-type-from-method)
[Return anonymous type results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/linq-to-sql-return-anonymous-type)
by the way Dto stand for Data Transfer Object

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<tbl_GameConfig> gameConfig = new List<tbl_GameConfig>();
 using (Entities con = new Entities())
  {
       gameConfig = con.tbl_GameConfig.Where(p => p.fk_GameTypeId == gameTypeId).ToList<tbl_GameConfig>();
  }
```