# How return custom anonymous type?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, anonymous-types, asp.net-web-api

How do I return an anonymous type which depends on the fields parameter in which properties which have to be included in anonymous type are listed? Task entity has more than 20 properties, and customers want to receive different combinations of properties.

```
public class Test
{
    public class Task
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        //... more 20 properties
    }

    public List<Task> Tasks = new List<Task>();

    public Test()
    {
        Tasks.Add(new Task { Id = 1, Name = "Task #1", Description = "Description task #1" });
        Tasks.Add(new Task { Id = 2, Name = "Task #2", Description = "Description task #2" });
        Tasks.Add(new Task { Id = 3, Name = "Task #3", Description = "Description task #3" });
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetAllTasks(string fields)
    {
        //if fields == 'Id,Name' then return anonymous type new { Id = t.Id, Name = t.Name }
        return Tasks.Select(t => new { Id = t.Id, Name = t.Name });

        //if fields == 'Id,Name,Description' then return anonymous type new { Id = t.Id, name = t.Name, Description = t.Description }
        return Tasks.Select(t => new { Id = t.Id, Name = t.Name, Description = t.Description });
    }
}
```

Comment: Anonymous types are known at compile type. You want to build types dynamically at runtime. That's quite different. It also means that consumers of `GetAllTasks` must be able to deal with dynamic types. Apart from that, returning anonymous types is not recommended.

Comment: You have defined class Task, why don't you use it rather than anonymous type?

Comment: You could use reflection to try to set the value of all the fields passed in on the Task object

Comment: Have you considered using a flags enum or other more structured approach for the client to communicate which fields they want returned?

Comment: The purpose - to reduce traffic between the server and the client (Web Api application). The client wants to receive only the information that it is really necessary. Standard JSON-serializer in web api is able to work / return anonymous objects. So, it is necessary to write the serializer that will save bandwidth?

Comment: In that case I would return a `dynamic` that you could construct by reflection as suggested above.

Comment: Or build a class which transfers your data to the proper JSON. Just put data into JSON, which is really required.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to return Anonymous Type from method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329672/is-there-a-way-to-return-anonymous-type-from-method)

Comment: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/01/09/horrible-grotty-hack-returning-an-anonymous-type-instance.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case if Tasks is `IQueryable<Task>` and we need to tighten from data source (for example, from a database) only those columns which are necessary for the client (not to overload the DB server), useful there is a [SelectDynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/723018) method. As a result the finished decision will be here such:

```
public class Test
{
    public class Task
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        //... more 20 properties
    }

    public IQueryable<Task> Tasks;

    public Test()
    {
        Tasks = new List<Task>
            {
                new Task {Id = 1, Name = "Task #1", Description = "Description task #1"},
                new Task {Id = 2, Name = "Task #2", Description = "Description task #2"},
                new Task {Id = 3, Name = "Task #3", Description = "Description task #3"}
            }.AsQueryable();
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetAllTasks(string[] fields)
    {
        var response = new List<object>();
        var customTasks = Tasks.SelectDynamic(fields).Cast<dynamic>();
        foreach (var t in customTasks.Take(100))
        {
            dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();

            if (fields.Contains("Id")) expando.Id = t.Id;
            if (fields.Contains("Name")) expando.Name = t.Name;
            if (fields.Contains("Description")) expando.Description = t.Description;
            // ... other properties

            response.Add(expando);
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

A sample usage is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14954742/2017821)

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will help you

```
public List<Task> Tasks = new List<Task>();

public void Test()
{
    Tasks.Add(new Task { Id = 1, Name = "Task #1", Description = "Description task #1" });
    Tasks.Add(new Task { Id = 2, Name = "Task #2", Description = "Description task #2" });
    Tasks.Add(new Task { Id = 3, Name = "Task #3", Description = "Description task #3" });
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    Test();

    return Json(GetAllTasks(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public IEnumerable<object> GetAllTasks()
{
    return Tasks.Select(GetTask);
}

private object GetTask(Task task)
{
    dynamic expandoObject = new ExpandoObject();
    //your if statment block
    if (task.Id == 1)
    {
        expandoObject.Id = task.Id;
    }

    expandoObject.Name = task.Name;
    expandoObject.Description = task.Description;

    var dictionary = expandoObject as IDictionary<string, object>;
    return dictionary.ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.Value);
}
```

the view result:

```
[
   [
      {
         "Key":"Id",
         "Value":1
      },
      {
         "Key":"Name",
         "Value":"Task #1"
      },
      {
         "Key":"Description",
         "Value":"Description task #1"
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "Key":"Name",
         "Value":"Task #2"
      },
      {
         "Key":"Description",
         "Value":"Description task #2"
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "Key":"Name",
         "Value":"Task #3"
      },
      {
         "Key":"Description",
         "Value":"Description task #3"
      }
   ]
]
```

Comment: Would you consider adding some narrative to explain why this code works, and what makes it an answer to the question? This would be very helpful to the person asking the question, and anyone else who comes along.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using the `ExpandoObject` and `System.Reflection`:

```
public IEnumerable<object> GetAllTasks(string[] fields)
{
    List<object> response = new List<object>();
    Tasks.ForEach((a) =>
    {
        dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
        var p = expando as IDictionary<String, object>;
        foreach (string item in fields)
        {
            p[item] = a.GetType().GetProperty(item).GetValue(a);
        }
        response.Add(expando);
    });
    return response;
}
```

And a sample usage is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var test = new Test();
    var results = test.GetAllTasks(new[] { "Id"});
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((result as dynamic).Id);
    }

    results = test.GetAllTasks(new[] { "Name", "Description" });
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        var dynamicResult=result as dynamic;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", dynamicResult.Name, dynamicResult.Description);
        // The following line will throw an exception
        //Console.WriteLine((result as dynamic).Id);
    }
}
```