# How to return generic List from method

Tags: c#, .net

I want to return from method an List of unknown type. I'm getting  error on the 'return' line of code.

```
public List<T> GetMethod<T>()
{
   var categoryCounts =
               (from r in reqCount
                group r by new
                {
                    r.First,
                    r.Second
                }
                into g
                select new
                      {
                        MonthNumber = g.Key.First,
                        Category = g.Key.Second,
                        OrdersCount = g.Count()
                      }).OrderBy(m => m.MonthNumber).ThenBy(c => c.Category).ToList();

   return categoryCounts;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to return Anonymous Type from method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329672/is-there-a-way-to-return-anonymous-type-from-method)

Comment: You cannot do this, as you're returning anonymous objects

Comment: I think your best bet is to use a dynamic variable, to get around the anonymous object

Comment: Just create a concrete class to hold the data and return this class instead of an anonymous type.

Comment: _Generic_ does not mean automatic conversion from any type to any other.

Answer (score 2):

You can't return anonymous types from a method.

You could return a `List<Object>`, but that won't really be generic.

Or, you could create a named type and return a List containing those:

```
public class MyType
{
    int MonthNumber {get;set;}
    string Category {get;set;}
    int OrdersCount {get;set;}
}

public List<MyType> GetMethod()
{
    var categoryCounts =
           (from r in reqCount
            group r by new
            {
                r.First,
                r.Second
            }
                into g
                select new MyType()
                {
                    MonthNumber = g.Key.First,
                    Category = g.Key.Second,
                    OrdersCount = g.Count()
                }).OrderBy(m => m.MonthNumber).ThenBy(c => c.Category).ToList();

    return categoryCounts;
}
```

Comment: _"You could return a List<Object>"_ that would compile, but apart from that it would be difficult to consume.

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<object> GetMethod(){}
```

or

```
public IList<object> GetMethod(){}
```

and then

```
var res = GetMethod();
res[0].YouFieldOrProp
```

You can't return anonymous types from a method.

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature returns a generic type, but the code within return a list of a *specific* anonymous type.  The compiler can't cast your anonymous type to whatever `T` is used by the caller. (GetMethod would not make sense with your implementation).

Without knowing how it's used, it's not clear whether your method *should* be generic or if you should be returning a concrete type.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the return type `dynamic`. You need to be very careful with this return type though. You lose compile-time checking, and intellisense will no longer work for the return object.