# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<>'

Tags: c#, linq

```
public IQueryable<DepartmentBreakdownReport> GetDepartmentBreakdownByReviewID(int ClientID, int? ReviewID) {
    var x = (from d in camOnlineDb.Details
             join h in camOnlineDb.Headers
             on new { d.ClientID, d.ClaimID }
             equals new { h.ClientID, h.ClaimID }
             where h.ClientID == d.ClientID

             join sd in camOnlineDb.SuppDepts
             on new { a = d.ClientID, b = d.CategoryID ?? 0 }
             equals new { a = sd.ClientID, b = sd.CategoryID }

             join r in camOnlineDb.Reviews
             on new { h.ClientID, h.ReviewID }
             equals new { r.ClientID, r.ReviewID }

             join rp in camOnlineDb.ReviewPeriods
             on new { a = r.ClientID, b = r.ReviewPeriodID ?? 0 }
             equals new { a = rp.ClientID, b = rp.ReviewPeriodID }

             select new {
                 d.ClientID,
                 h.ReviewID,
                 sd.DepartmentID,
                 sd.DepartmentName,
                 d.Amount
             });

    x.GroupBy(r => new { r.DepartmentID, r.ReviewID, r.ClientID })
    .Select(g => new {
        ClientID = g.Key.ClientID,
        ReviewID = g.Key.ReviewID,
        Dept = g.Max(d => d.DepartmentName),
        Amount = g.Sum(d => d.Amount)
    })
    .OrderBy(r => r.Dept)
    .Where(r => r.ReviewID == 37);
    //.Dump();

    return x;
```

I know it has something to do with returning x. I tried returning is asQueryable but this didn't work. How do I get my statement to return x?

Comment: You are selecting an anonymous type bye `.Select(g => new` you can't return it like that, search of [returning anonymous types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329672/is-there-a-way-to-return-anonymous-type-from-method)

Comment: There is at least one error... Starting with `x.GroupBy`, you aren't saving the result anywhere... That `GroupBy` will be discarded.

Comment: @Habib Technically he could return a `IQueryable<object>`, but 99% it would be useless (`IQueryable<>` is covariant)

Comment: Hi, DepartmentBreakdownReport does contain all the fields I wish to set. However I need to group and order some of my results. I need to know how to return a set of results that have this sorted data within it

Comment: `DepartmentBreakdownReport` looks like to be a framework generated entity, I don't think it could be used in project with `Select`

Comment: @Habib It's not EF generated. I generated the class myself as a way to store data in order to get it to my view

Comment: Re-opening the question, as it is not really about returning an anonymous type

Comment: @AndrewKilburn, also assign the result of your last query to something, your last query is being discarded, as xanatos pointed out.

Comment: @GrantWinney It does not return an exception. And in regards to your second comment does that mean I shall remove the groupby from the statement before?

Answer (score 0):

x is an `IQueryable<T>` where the `T` is the anonymous type with `ClientID`, `ReviewID`, `DepartmentID`, `DepartmentName` and `Amount` methods.

At some point you need to do a either a `select new DepartmentBreakdownReport(…)`, as `select new DepartmentBreakdownReport{…}` a `.Select(something => new DepartmentBreakdownReport(…))` or a `.Select(something => new DepartmentBreakdownReport{…})`. (Which are all the same thing really.

That will then give you an `IQueryable<DepartmentBreakdownReport>` because the type it has selected will be `DepartmentBreakdownReport`.

Note also that the code `x.GroupBy(r => new { r.DepartmentID, r.ReviewID, r.ClientID })` and so on in your code effectively does nothing; it creates a new query, but then that new query is never used or even touched.

Answer (score 0):

What I meant by my earlier comment(s) is that you want to create (and return) instances of `DepartmentBreakdownReport`, not an anonymous type.

```
return x.Where(r => r.ReviewID == 37)
        .GroupBy(r => new { r.DepartmentID, r.ReviewID, r.ClientID })
        .Select(g => new DepartmentBreakdownReport
                         {
                             ClientID = g.Key.ClientID,
                             ReviewID = g.Key.ReviewID,
                             Dept = g.Max(d => d.DepartmentName),
                             Amount = g.Sum(d => d.Amount)
                         })
        .OrderBy(r => r.Dept);
```

I reordered the query a bit to my personal taste, but it should produce the same results.

Also, I don't know if you'll have to add an `AsQueryable()` on to the end of that or not...