# What's the difference between System.ValueTuple and System.Tuple?

Tags: c#, .net, tuples, c#-7.0

I decompiled some C# 7 libraries and saw `ValueTuple` generics being used. What are `ValueTuples` and why not `Tuple` instead?

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.tuple
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple

Comment: I think its referring to Dot NEt Tuple class. Could you please share a sample code. So that it would be easy to understand.

Comment: @Ranadip Dutta: If you know what a tuple is, you don't need sample code to understand the question. The question itself is straightforward: what is ValueTuple and how does it differ from Tuple?

Comment: @BoltClock: That is the reason I did not answer anything on that context. I know in c# , there is a Tuple class which I use pretty frequently and same class some times I call it in powershell also. Its a reference type. Now seeing the other answers I understood that there is a value type also which is known as Valuetuple. If there is a sample I would like to know the usage for the same.

Comment: Why do you decompile these when the source code for Roslyn is available on github ?

Comment: @user3185569 probably because F12 auto-decompiles things and its easier than jumping to GitHub

Comment: This is a pretty good summary of what it is and its limitation https://josephwoodward.co.uk/2017/04/csharp-7-valuetuple-types-and-their-limitations

Comment: @John Zabroski: "F12 auto-decompiles"?! Not for me. How did you instruct your system to do that?

Comment: @jensmander it's probably ReSharper

Comment: Yeah, at least on VS 17 and 19 only after ReSharper is enable does F12 auto-decompiles things.

Answer (score 276, accepted):

> What are `ValueTuples` and why not `Tuple` instead?

A [`ValueTuple`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/8e3376c4c2d184e7e351daad65dc8a7df9f82f4f/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/ValueTuple.cs#L34C5-L34C29) is a struct which reflects a tuple, same as the original `System.Tuple` class.

The main difference between `Tuple` and `ValueTuple` are:

- `System.ValueTuple` is a value type (struct), while `System.Tuple` is a reference type (`class`). This is meaningful when talking about allocations and GC pressure.
- `System.ValueTuple` isn't only a `struct`, it's a *mutable* one, and one has to be careful when using them as such. Think what happens when a class holds a `System.ValueTuple` as a field.
- `System.ValueTuple` exposes its items via fields instead of properties.

Until C# 7, using tuples wasn't very convenient. Their field names are `Item1`, `Item2`, etc, and the language hadn't supplied syntax sugar for them like most other languages do (Python, Scala).

When the .NET language design team decided to incorporate tuples and add syntax sugar to them at the language level an important factor was performance. With `ValueTuple` being a value type, you can avoid GC pressure when using them because (as an implementation detail) they'll be allocated on the stack.

Additionally, a `struct` gets automatic (shallow) equality semantics by the runtime, where a `class` doesn't. Although the design team made sure there will be an even more optimized equality for tuples, hence implemented a custom equality for it.

Here is a paragraph from the [design notes of `Tuples`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/347):

> ## Struct or Class:
>
> As mentioned, I propose to make tuple types `structs` rather than
> `classes`, so that no allocation penalty is associated with them. They
> should be as lightweight as possible.
>
> Arguably, `structs` can end up being more costly, because assignment
> copies a bigger value. So if they are assigned a lot more than they
> are created, then `structs` would be a bad choice.
>
> In their very motivation, though, tuples are ephemeral. You would use
> them when the parts are more important than the whole. So the common
> pattern would be to construct, return and immediately deconstruct
> them. In this situation structs are clearly preferable.
>
> Structs also have a number of other benefits, which will become
> obvious in the following.

---

## Examples:

You can easily see that working with `System.Tuple` becomes ambiguous very quickly. For example, say we have a method which calculates a sum and a count of a `List<Int>`:

```
public Tuple<int, int> DoStuff(IEnumerable<int> values)
{
    var sum = 0;
    var count = 0;
    
    foreach (var value in values) { sum += value; count++; }
   
    return new Tuple(sum, count);
}
```

On the receiving end, we end up with:

```
Tuple<int, int> result = DoStuff(Enumerable.Range(0, 10));

// What is Item1 and what is Item2?
// Which one is the sum and which is the count?
Console.WriteLine(result.Item1);
Console.WriteLine(result.Item2);
```

The way you can deconstruct value tuples into named arguments is the real power of the feature:

```
public (int sum, int count) DoStuff(IEnumerable<int> values) 
{
    var res = (sum: 0, count: 0);
    foreach (var value in values) { res.sum += value; res.count++; }
    return res;
}
```

And on the receiving end:

```
var result = DoStuff(Enumerable.Range(0, 10));
Console.WriteLine($"Sum: {result.sum}, Count: {result.count}");
```

Or:

```
var (sum, count) = DoStuff(Enumerable.Range(0, 10));
Console.WriteLine($"Sum: {sum}, Count: {count}");
```

---

## Compiler goodies:

If we look under the cover of our previous example, we can see exactly how the compiler is interpreting `ValueTuple` when we ask it to deconstruct:

```
[return: TupleElementNames(new string[] {
    "sum",
    "count"
})]
public ValueTuple<int, int> DoStuff(IEnumerable<int> values)
{
    ValueTuple<int, int> result;
    result..ctor(0, 0);
    foreach (int current in values)
    {
        result.Item1 += current;
        result.Item2++;
    }
    return result;
}

public void Foo()
{
    ValueTuple<int, int> expr_0E = this.DoStuff(Enumerable.Range(0, 10));
    int item = expr_0E.Item1;
    int arg_1A_0 = expr_0E.Item2;
}
```

Internally, the compiled code utilizes `Item1` and `Item2`, but all of this is abstracted away from us since we work with a decomposed tuple. A tuple with named arguments gets annotated with the [`TupleElementNamesAttribute`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Compilers/Test/Resources/Core/NetFX/ValueTuple/TupleElementNamesAttribute.cs). If we use a single fresh variable instead of decomposing, we get:

```
public void Foo()
{
    ValueTuple<int, int> valueTuple = this.DoStuff(Enumerable.Range(0, 10));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Sum: {0}, Count: {1})", valueTuple.Item1, valueTuple.Item2));
}
```

Note that the compiler still has to make some magic happen (via the attribute) when we debug our application, as it would be odd to see `Item1`, `Item2`.

Comment: Note that you can also use the simpler (and in my opinion, preferable) syntax `var (sum, count) = DoStuff(Enumerable.Range(0, 10));`

Comment: @Abion47 What would happen if both types differ?

Comment: Also how do your points "it's a *mutable* struct" and "it exposes *readonly* fields" agree?

Comment: @CodesInChaos It doesn't. I saw [this ](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/System/ValueTuple.cs), but I don't think that's what end up being emitted by the compiler, since local fields cannot be readonly anyway. I think the proposal meant *"you can make them readonly if you wish, but that is up to you"*, which I misinterpreted.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Nothing happens. That syntax is merely shorthand for the syntax you provided. It makes no assumptions or limitations of the types of the tuple fields.

Comment: Some nits: _"they'll be allocated on the stack"_ -- true only for local variables. No doubt you know this, but unfortunately, the way you've phrased this is likely to perpetuate the myth that value types always live in the stack.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you for that. I've been doing a lot of Scala lately, where the compiler is actually the one which generates custom equality comparison for record types (so I've gotten spoiled by it). Updated the answer to reflect the comments.

Comment: Is Tuple2 your own struct tuple type? Looks like everybody needs a struct tuple in their personal utils library.

Comment: @usr Typo :p. Fixed it

Answer (score 35):

The difference between `Tuple` and `ValueTuple` is that `Tuple` is a reference type and `ValueTuple` is a value type. The latter is desirable because changes to the language in C# 7 have tuples being used much more frequently, but allocating a new object on the heap for every tuple is a performance concern, particularly when it's unnecessary.

However, in C# 7, the idea is that you never *have* to explicitly use either type because of the syntax sugar being added for tuple use. For example, in C# 6, if you wanted to use a tuple to return a value, you would have to do the following:

```
public Tuple<string, int> GetValues()
{
    // ...
    return new Tuple(stringVal, intVal);
}

var value = GetValues();
string s = value.Item1;
```

However, in C# 7, you can use this:

```
public (string, int) GetValues()
{
    // ...
    return (stringVal, intVal);
}

var value = GetValues();
string s = value.Item1;
```

You can even go a step further and give the values names:

```
public (string S, int I) GetValues()
{
    // ...
    return (stringVal, intVal);
}

var value = GetValues();
string s = value.S;
```

... Or deconstruct the tuple entirely:

```
public (string S, int I) GetValues()
{
    // ...
    return (stringVal, intVal);
}

var (S, I) = GetValues();
string s = S;
```

Tuples weren't often used in C# pre-7 because they were cumbersome and verbose, and only really used in cases where building a data class/struct for just a single instance of work would be more trouble than it was worth. But in C# 7, tuples have language-level support now, so using them is much cleaner and more useful.

Comment: if you return `(string S, int I)` then it's no longer `Tuple` but instead a `ValueTuple`, which is a different thing. Say if you return a private field of a class, then Tuple(reference type) could be better from a performance perspective?

Comment: @joe In the strictest sense, maybe, but you could use the same logic to never use a value type for anything and it's a micro-optimization at best. You lose out on the language support and helpful tools offered for `ValueTuple` in exchange for a handful of nanoseconds on the return time. On the other hand, you also lose at least that much time whenever you need to dereference (i.e. unbox) the values. And finally, if you are storing tuples as private class values, that's code smell to me. If you're storing bundles of data as class data, use a class/struct, not a tuple.

Comment: I just feel the code smell when you return, say a "steady"  ValueTuple<structA, structB> (might be a field of a class on heap), but you have to copy it every time it's assigned(see the accepted answer). You are probably right in terms of "handful" and the trade-offs.

Comment: @joe If we're talking primitive value types like `int`, `bool`, and even to a certain extent `string`, copying the value for the return is faster than wrapping it in a reference type and subsequently unwrapping it later. That's what you do anyway when you have a getter function or property that returns a class field of a primitive type. Returning a `ValueType` falls under the same category of performance, especially if the fields of the tuple are themselves primitive types.

Answer (score 16):

I looked at the source for both `Tuple` and `ValueTuple`. The difference is that `Tuple` is a `class` and `ValueTuple` is a `struct` that implements `IEquatable`.

That means that `Tuple == Tuple` will return `false` if they are not the same instance, but `ValueTuple == ValueTuple` will return `true` if they are of the same type and `Equals` returns `true` for each of the values they contain.

Comment: It's more than that though.

Comment: @BoltClock Your comment would be constructive if you were to elaborate

Comment: Also, value types don't necessarily go on the stack.  The difference is that the semantically represent the value, rather than a reference, whenever that variable is stored, which may or may not be the stack.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the comments above, one unfortunate gotcha of ValueTuple is that, as a value type, the named arguments get erased when compiled to IL, so they're not available for serialisation at runtime.

i.e. Your sweet named arguments will still end up as "Item1", "Item2", etc. when serialised via e.g. Json.NET.

Comment: So technically that's a similarity and not a difference ;)

Answer (score 6):

Other answers forgot to mention important points.Instead of rephrasing, I'm gonna reference the XML documentation from [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.ValueTuple/src/System/ValueTuple/ValueTuple.cs):

The ValueTuple types (from arity 0 to 8) comprise the runtime implementation that underlies 
tuples in C# and struct tuples in F#.

**Aside from created via language syntax**, they are most easily created via the 
`ValueTuple.Create` factory methods.
The `System.ValueTuple` types differ from the `System.Tuple` types in that:

- they are structs rather than classes,
- **they are mutable rather than readonly**, and
- their members (such as Item1, Item2, etc) are fields rather than properties.

With introduction of this type and C# 7.0 compiler, you can easily write

```
(int, string) idAndName = (1, "John");
```

And return two values from a method:

```
private (int, string) GetIdAndName()
{
   //.....
   return (id, name);
}
```

Contrary to `System.Tuple` you can update its members (Mutable) because they are public read-write Fields that can be given meaningful names:

```
(int id, string name) idAndName = (1, "John");
idAndName.name = "New Name";
```

Comment: "Arity 0 to 8". Ah, I like the fact that they include a 0-tuple. It could be used as a kind of empty type, and will be allowed in generics when some type parameter is not needed, like in `class MyNonGenericType : MyGenericType<string, ValueTuple, int>` etc.

Answer (score 3):

Late-joining to add a quick clarification on these two factoids:

- they are structs rather than classes
- they are mutable rather than readonly

One would think that changing value-tuples en-masse would be straightforward:

```
 foreach (var x in listOfValueTuples) { x.Foo = 103; } // wont even compile because x is a value (struct) not a variable

 var d = listOfValueTuples[0].Foo;
```

Someone might try to workaround this like so:

```
 // initially *.Foo = 10 for all items
 listOfValueTuples.Select(x => x.Foo = 103);

 var d = listOfValueTuples[0].Foo; // 'd' should be 103 right? wrong! it is '10'
```

The reason for this quirky behavior is that the value-tuples are exactly value-based (structs) and thus the .Select(...) call works on cloned-structs rather than on the originals. To resolve this we must resort to:

```
 // initially *.Foo = 10 for all items
 listOfValueTuples = listOfValueTuples
     .Select(x => {
         x.Foo = 103;
         return x;
     })
     .ToList();

 var d = listOfValueTuples[0].Foo; // 'd' is now 103 indeed
```

Alternatively of course one might try the straightforward approach:

```
   for (var i = 0; i < listOfValueTuples.Length; i++) {
        listOfValueTuples[i].Foo = 103; //this works just fine

        // another alternative approach:
        //
        // var x = listOfValueTuples[i];
        // x.Foo = 103;
        // listOfValueTuples[i] = x; //<-- vital for this alternative approach to work   if you omit this changes wont be saved to the original list
   }

   var d = listOfValueTuples[0].Foo; // 'd' is now 103 indeed
```

Hope this helps someone struggling to make heads of tails out of list-hosted value-tuples.