# Casting new tuple to old one gives compilation error

Tags: c#, tuples, c#-7.0

With the code below,

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Tuple<int, int> test = TupleTest();

    }

    static (int, int) TupleTest()
    {
        return (1, 2);
    }
```

I am getting following compile time error.

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type '(int, int)' to
>   'System.Tuple < int, int >'

Does it mean the new version of Tuple is not compatible with the old version implicitly? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: The "new tuple" is a different type called [`System.ValueTuple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetuple(v=vs.110).aspx) (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41084411/whats-the-difference-between-system-valuetuple-and-system-tuple) for a discussion of the differences) and AFAIK there are no plans to make it implicitly convertible to `System.Tuple`

Comment: As Matej answered below you should use the extension methods (`ToTuple`).
The reason those cannot be implemented as user-defined conversions is that we need them to go above arity 7.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yeah, you should use extension method [ToTuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tupleextensions.totuple(v=vs.110).aspx). So in your example...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Tuple<int, int> test = TupleTest().ToTuple();

    }

    static (int, int) TupleTest()
    {
        return (1, 2);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

- Use `ValueTuple` instead:

  ```cs
  ValueTuple<int, int> test = TupleTest();
  ```
- Use the `ToTuple` extension method (`ToValueTuple` is also available):

  ```cs
  Tuple<int, int> test = TupleTest().ToTuple();
  ```