# is the ValueTuple structure only mutable as variable?

Tags: c#, immutability, mutability, valuetuple

I played around with the `ValueTuple` structure and tried to implement an immutable composite key. The key is composed of value types.

I tried to break the following implementation with some unit tests, so far without success. Am I missing something?

Also this is just out of curiosity, I want to get to `ValueTuple`s and it's limitations before the release of .NET 4.7.

So far my understanding of  a `ValueTuple` is that it is only mutable as a variable but not as a field or property. Not sure what "mutable" means here though. Does altering a `ValueTuple` instance *actually* create a new `ValueTuple` (like it's common knowledge that strings are "immutable" but *actually* reference types)?

> *from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41084470/1154965)*
>
> `System.ValueTuple` isn't only a `struct`, it's a *mutable* one, and one has to be careful when using them as such. Think what happens when a class holds a `System.ValueTuple` as a field.

Here my implementation and tests

```
public interface IHaveCompositeKey
{
    (Guid id, string name) Key { get; }
}

public class ImmutableKey : IHaveCompositeKey
{
    public (Guid id, string name) Key { get; }
    public ImmutableKey((Guid id, string name) key) => Key = key;
    public override int GetHashCode() => Key.GetHashCode();
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var a = obj as ImmutableKey;
        return a != null && Key.Equals(a.Key);
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class KeyTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Test1() // passes
    {
        var key = (Guid.NewGuid(), "Foo");
        var a = new ImmutableKey(key);
        var b = new ImmutableKey(key);
        Assert.IsTrue(a.Equals(b));
        Assert.IsTrue(a.GetHashCode().Equals(b.GetHashCode()));
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test2() // passes
    {
        (Guid id, string name) key = (Guid.NewGuid(), "Foo");
        var a = new ImmutableKey(key);
        key.name = "Bar"; // mutable
        var b = new ImmutableKey(key);
        Assert.IsFalse(a.Equals(b));
        Assert.IsFalse(a.GetHashCode().Equals(b.GetHashCode()));
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test3() // does not compile
    {
        var key = (Guid.NewGuid(), "Foo");
        var a = new ImmutableKey(key);
        // compilation error
        a.Key.name = "Bar"; // immutable
        var b = new ImmutableKey(a.Key);
        Assert.IsFalse(a.Equals(b));
        Assert.IsFalse(a.GetHashCode().Equals(b.GetHashCode()));
    }
}
```

> error: Cannot modify the return value of 'ImmutableKey.Key' because it is not a variable

Comment: Do you know difference between property and field?

Comment: Oh, I did but I did't understand the behavior of `struct`s (and `ValueTuple` is implemented as `struct`) when exposed by properties. If I implement `Key` as public field it "works". Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are three cases when one can change mutable struct and see result:

- local variable: `MyStruct s = new MyStruct(); s.Prop = 4;`
- *field* of another type: `class MyType { public MyStruct S;} ... myType.S.Prop = 4;`
- element of *array*: `MyStruct[] myArray =...; myArray[3].Prop = 4;`.

Why code in the post did not detect change - code used *property* and not a field.

Note that `List<MyStruct>` does not allow modification because indexer (`this[..]`) returns copy of an item (as there is no support returning reference like C++ does).