# Can a C# named Tuple be used as an MVC page model type?

Tags: c#, model, tuples, named, c#-7.0

In C# 7 you can have named tuples:

```
var foo = (Name: "Joe", Age: 42);
```

If I pass this to a MVC model using:

```
return View(foo);
```

Then what syntax should be used in the cshtml file to declare the model? Although this doesn't work, something like...

```
@model (string Name, int Age);
```

Comment: I would recommend doing this for the same reason that I was given to not have your model implement `List<T>`: What happens if you need to add another property/collection? Yes, you can expand your Tuple easier than just a list, however, it could get messy very easily. Make a Model. It's MVC, not TVC.

Comment: I didn't read about the new C# 7 features yet, but maybe: `ValueTuple<string, int>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for current time you can't and need to use

```
@model Tuple<string, int>
//or
@model ValueTuple<string, int>
```

For the difference between the two options: [What's the difference between System.ValueTuple and System.Tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41084411/6400526)

You can follow on GitHub: [Razor throws CompilationFailedException when iterating over named Tuple](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/1070) *(I know it is closed as a dup but name is more indicative for current case)*

Comment: Yeppers; I did end up doing this, but sure wish I could have done something like:

@model (string: Name, int: Age);

I can live with this for now. :-)

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is a bug in Razor 2.0.0  - tracked here https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/1592. This will be fixed in 2.1.0

Comment: @RyanNowak - Thanks - I'll keep track and update my answer in time