# Can I use anonymous types as a Razor model?

Tags: c#, razor, types, anonymous-types

I have a C# server where I manually render some Razor views using the `RazorEngine` NuGet library. The model supplied to the view is an anonymous type, created as follows:

```
new[] { Foo = "Bar", Baz = "Example" }
```

Because of the way I'm rendering my template, Visual Studio isn't aware of my model. This means that Visual Studio considers code like this invalid, even though it works fine:

```
<p>@Model.Foo</p>
```

To rectify this, I have discovered the `@model` directive, but this appears only to work with classes as the specified model. For example, these are both considered invalid:

```
@model { string Foo, string Baz }
@model (string Foo, string Baz)
```

Is there any way I can get `@model` to work with anonymous types? Alternatively, named tuples would satisfy the compiler too, since I never update any of my model's fields from the template.

Comment: You can use `@model Tuple<string, string>` etc, could probably use dynamic too

Comment: @Ric That would work for an unnamed tuple, but not for a named one like `(string Foo, string Baz)`. I've updated my question to clarify.

Comment: Not used named tuples yet, but see here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842565/can-a-c-sharp-named-tuple-be-used-as-an-mvc-page-model-type

Comment: If model is always the same (static) - why not just create separate class for it?

Comment: @Evk that's probably what I'll do - I'd still like to know if it's possible this way though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but I wouldn't normally as strongly typed view models have their advantages.

Create your model like this:

```
dynamic model = new ExpandoObject();
model.Foo = "Bar";
model.Baz = "Example";
```

And then you can access it in the view, no problem

```
<h1>@Model.Foo</h1>
<h2>@Model.Baz</h2>
```

NB. By default a `RazorPage<T>` is defined as `RazorPage<dynamic>`, so there's no need to declare `@model dynamic`.

Comment: There's no problem with the *function* of my templates; the problem is that Visual Studio thinks there's a problem when in fact there is not, because the IDE is not aware of my model. Also, using an `ExpandoObject` as the model parameter of `RazorEngine.Engine.Razor.RunCompile` does not compile. Thanks for replying though.