# how can access to tuple item in asp.net-mvc 5 view c#7.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i used *c# 7.2* (c# latest minor version (latest))

I want to send two model with **Tuple** and named items  in view.
in controller i create tuple with name:

```
   public ActionResult Create(Guid fitnessPlanId)
        {
            #region GetCurrentFitnessPlan

            var currentFitnessPlan= _service.FitnessPlanRepository.Get(fitnessPlanId, null, null);
            if (currentFitnessPlan == null) return HttpNotFound();

            #endregion
            _currentUser = _service.UserRepository.GetUserByUsername(User.Identity.Name);

           (FitnessPlan fitnessPlan , FitnessPlanDay fitnessPlanDay) tupleModel =(currentFitnessPlan, null);  

            return View(tupleModel);
        }
```

and in view i wrote this:

```
@model (FitnessPlan fitnessPlan, FitnessPlanDay fitnessPlanDay)
```

when use tuple in view like this:

```
<th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fitnessPlan.User.Sex)</th>
```

**DisplayNameFor** take me an error:

> The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying
>   the type arguments explicitly.

I did research on the Internet, but I did not find any results.
How can use Tuple By naming items in view ?

**---Fixed---**

Regarding the answer *Georg Patscheider* and this article :[Can a C# named Tuple be used as an MVC page model type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842565/can-a-c-sharp-named-tuple-be-used-as-an-mvc-page-model-type)

The only way to fix this problem was to change             `var tupleModel = new Tuple<FitnessPlan, FitnessPlanDay>(currentFitnessPlan, null);` in action controller and
 the model to `@model Tuple<FitnessPlan, FitnessPlanDay>`on the view and use                         `<th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Item1.User.Sex)</th>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clean way to handle this would be to introduce a new ViewModel that wraps `FitnessPlan` and `FitnessPlanDay`.

```
public CreateFitnessPlanViewModel {
    public FitnessPlan Plan { get; set; }
    public FitnessPlanDay Day { get; set; }
}
```

Razor:

```
@model CreateFitnessPlanViewModel
<th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Plan.User.Sex)</th>
```

---

That being said, you can access the elements of tuples with `Item1`, `Item2`, ... `ItemN`:

```
var tuple = new Tuple<FitnessPlan, FitnessPlanDay>(fitnessPlan, fitnessPlanDay);
var plan = tuple.Item1;
var day = tuple.Item2;
```

So you can use:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Item1.User.Sex)
```

Comment: Right to you. Useful information for people like me :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842565/can-a-c-sharp-named-tuple-be-used-as-an-mvc-page-model-type

Comment: OP's method is `Create()` suggesting its a view for creating/editing data which means you cannot use a `Tuple` (it has no paeameterless constructor therefore cannot be bound in the POST method). And view models should **not** contain data models