# What's the difference between System.Tuple and (,)?

Tags: c#, tuples

Background: I am using two methods from different libraries; one uses `System.Tuple<double,double>` and the other uses `(double,double)` for arguments. I am finding myself unable to utilize both methods without doing extra work to convert a `System.Tuple` to a `(,)`.

What is the difference between `System.Tuple<t1,t2>` and `(t1,t2)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`(t1,t2)` is a `ValueTuple<,>` not a `Tuple<,>`

So doing the following will work:

```
ValueTuple<int, int> hey = (1, 2);
```

However, this will give you a type error

```
 Tuple<int, int> hey = (1, 2);
```

More information on the difference between `ValueTuple` and `Tuple` can be found on this question/answers [What's the difference between System.ValueTuple and System.Tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41084411/whats-the-difference-between-system-valuetuple-and-system-tuple)

Comment: Tuple<int, int> tuple = Tuple.Create(i, k);

Answer (score 0):

Tuple represents a single set of data. You can pass multiple values to a method by through a single Tuple parameter. You can return set of data using Tuple without using the out parameter. You can use Tuple to pass or return a max of 8 parameters from a method.