# Tuple.Create : The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: c#, tuples

I'm trying To make the method to return a Tuple of: `Tuple<DateTime?, DateTime?>`.

In case the code is being able to generate two DateTime types, I'm uses the `Tuple.Create` to create a return statement with:

```
public Tuple<DateTime?, DateTime?> GeTuple()
{
    if (something)
    {
        return Tuple.Create(startDate, endDate);
    }
    else
    {
        return Tuple.Create(null, null); //--> This line produce the error.
    }
}
```

but I'm getting this error of:

> The type arguments for method 'Tuple.Create(T1, T2)' cannot be
>   inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: The compiler can't look at `Tuple.Create(null, null)` and tell that you meant to create a `Tuple<DateTime?, DateTime?>`. Use `new Tuple<DateTime?, DateTime?>(null, null)` or `Tuple.Create((DateTime?)null, (DateTime?)null)`

Comment: Tnx, it works..

Comment: Expanded it to a full answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler can't look at `Tuple.Create(null, null)` and tell that you meant to create a `Tuple<DateTime?, DateTime?>`. The fact that it's then being returned from a method which returns a `Tuple<DateTime?, DateTime?>` doesn't matter: the compiler doesn't consider that.

Use one of these:

```
new Tuple<DateTime?, DateTime?>(null, null)

Tuple.Create((DateTime?)null, (DateTime?)null)
```

Answer (score 3):

As a complementary answer of @canton7's answer, I just want to add that C# 7 introduced a new struct called ValueTuple that has explicit support by the compiler:

So your code can take advantage of it as follows :

```
public (DateTime?, DateTime?) GeTuple() => boolean-expression ? (startDate, endDate) : (default(DateTime?), default(DateTime?));
```

Note that (DateTime?, DateTime?) is just syntactic sugar for :

```
System.ValueTuple<DateTime?, DateTime?>.
```

This [Stackoveflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41084411/whats-the-difference-between-system-valuetuple-and-system-tuple) has answers that go deeper into the difference between the Tuple class and the ValueTuple struct and when to use what.