# dictionaries to tuple list

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary, tuples

Short question. Is there a way to do this with Linq or any other default solution?

Two dictionaries with same key but different values to a tuple list. The list should contain only values, where both dictionaries had a matching key.

```
public static List<Tuple<TOut1, TOut2>> ParseToTupleList<TKey, TOut1, TOut2>(
    IDictionary<TKey, TOut1> a,
    IDictionary<TKey, TOut2> b)
{
    var list = new List<Tuple<TOut1, TOut2>>(a.Count());

    foreach (var keyValue in a)
    {
        if (b.TryGetValue(keyValue.Key, out var bValue))
        {
            list.Add(new Tuple<TOut1, TOut2>(keyValue.Value, bValue));
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you currently have?

Comment: @gunr2171 I just did wonder if there are other options or default solutions to this. Pure educational interest from my side.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to match title "dictionaries to value tuple list" and sample in the body of the question that shows `Tuple`. Consider re-reading the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41084411/whats-the-difference-between-system-valuetuple-and-system-tuple to help with the right terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `Where()` instead of the `if`, and a `Select()` instead of the `list.Add`.

```
return a
    .Where(aEntry => b.ContainsKey(aEntry.Key))
    .Select(aEntry => new Tuple<TOut1, TOut2>(aEntry.Value, b[aEntry.Key]))
    .ToList();
```

Normally, "Contains" would be an O(n) operation, but with a dictionary it's O(1), so that's not a performance impact. You could also rewrite this to use a `join` instead, matching A's entry on B's entry by key.

```
return (from aEntry in a
        join bEntry in b on aEntry.Key equals bEntry.Key
        select new Tuple<TOut1, TOut2>(aEntry.Value, bEntry.Value)).ToList();
```

Comment: Join uses lookup dictionary internally.

Comment: I guess the join approach would also have the advantage to work with more than two dictionaries and would be more flexible because of that.

Comment: Note that OP asked for `select (aEntry.Value, bEntry.Value))` - "dictionaries to value tuple list" and not `Tuple` as shown in the answer... Now since they accepted the answer...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov oh I see, my bad. The normal Tuple type is what I meant. I will change the tags and title.

Comment: I'd also change the method to return `IEnumerable<TOut1, TOut2>` and remove the `ToList()` at the end.