# Why were anonymous types designed not to be returned by methods?

Tags: c#

In answering this question: [Is there a way to return Anonymous Type from method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329672/is-there-a-way-to-return-anonymous-type-from-method), Andrew Hare states that

*Returning it as a System.Object is the only way to return an anonymous type from a method. Unfortunately there is no other way to do this since anonymous types were designed specifically to prevent their use in this way.*

Can anyone elaborate on that?

I mean that the C# team could have implemented the equivalent of the `var` keyword for method return types, and type the method based on the type of the return statement.

as in:

```
public var myMethod()
{
    var x = new {A="blah"};
    return x;
}
```

And then let the type inference do the job for the consuming functions.

That would have been helpful for Linq statements that want to call methods instead of chaining lambdas (which **can** return anonymous types, btw).

But apparently, this was done by design. I can't see the trade-off though, does anyone know?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: what I meant is that the code that is emitted for the lambda does contain a method that returns the anonymous type.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: ah! interfaces, and inheritance in general, that's a good point indeed!

Comment: I'll leave it unanswered for a while, to see if anyone else has some other idea :)

Comment: In [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/534710/215552) Jon Skeet mentions it is possible, but extremely only with a horrible hack, and links to his blog, where he tells people not to use it :).

Comment: First, your question is based on a false statement. Methods _can_ return anonymous types, if they are generic. Happens in LINQ-based code all the time. As for why you can't declare a method to return a _specific_ anonymous type, i.e. one declared within that method, for anyone other than the language designers, that's a matter of opinion. There are some obvious difficulties that would arise if this were allowed (some are discussed in the "answers" you got). But at the end of the day, it's really just for whatever reason the language designers had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a guess, and you said you could find no trade-offs. One major one is it can't be used for interfaces.

Show me how you would put `myMethod()` in a interface then consume it from another assembly that only has a copy of the interface to reference and can't reference the implementation.

There is no way to represent the annonamous type in the interface and making it so "you can use interfaces on all public non-static methods, except for the ones with a implicit return type" would be too much of a departure of the standard pattern.

If you are using C# 7 you could use the new Tuples feature to achieve a similar goal.

```
public (string A, int Answer) myMethod()
{
    return (A: "Blah", Answer: 42);
}
```

This can be used with a interface

```
public interface IExample
{
    (string A, int Answer) myMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Think that sharing an anonymous type outside a given method body would mean that the whole type may be **more** useful than you expect. For example, you might want to inherit it, implement an interface on it.

Also, what would happen when you would want to upcast an anonymously-typed object to `object` and later to the anonymous type again...? You would have lost the type after all... There're too many issues to solve and it's a sign to think that anonymous types are just fine right now.

Basically this is the reason to avoid exposing *anonymous types* outsides the boundaries of their limited scope.

Actually anonymous types are *named types* once they get built into *intermediate language* (IL). That is, it's a syntactic sugar provided by the C# grammar/compiler to lie you and make you believe that you're creating a typed object as you instantiate it.

Another point of view to understand *why anonymous type shouldn't be exposed that way* is that it would be painful to maintain and evolve a strongly-typed code base on which you need to look into method bodies to check how's the whole type...

Anyway, you might be interested in [C#7's tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/csharp-7#tuples):

```
public (string x, int y) DoStuff()
{
     return ("hello world", 283);
}
```

Aren't tuples what you propose for anonymous types? ;)

Comment: Yes, tuples will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing runtime behavior with compile time behavior.  Imagine if your code looked like this:

```
public var myMethod(int i)
{
    if (i = 0) {
        var x = new {A="blah"};
        return x;
        }
    else {
       var a = new {K=14};
       return a;
       }
}
```

How would type inference work in that case?  It would be confused because the returned type could be anything.  You could return a Tuple<> or a dynamic type both have there pros and cons.

Comment: Good point too!

Comment: @Dweeberly: these are different types, so that would compile to an error, the same error you'd get if you did: `var a = b ? new {A="blah"} : new {K=14};`