# return the result of all the query as List of not known type

Tags: c#, linq

I have new table created after join multiple tables together. I would like to know how to return the result of all the query as List of not known type.

```
private List<T> GetLabelFieldValue(IOrderDetails orderDetail)
{
    var checkDataBase = from app in DatabaseContext.x.r
                        join app2 in DatabaseContext.x.r2 on app.OrderLabelId equals app2.Id
                        join app3 in DatabaseContext.x.r3 on app2.SalesOrderId equals app3.Id
                        select new
                        {
                            app2.SalesOrderId,
                            app.LabelVariableName,
                            app.FieldValue,
                            app3.SalesOrderNo
                        };
    var toInt = Convert.ToInt32(orderDetail.SalesOrder);
    var fieldValue = checkDataBase.Where(a => a.SalesOrderNo.Equals(toInt));

    return fieldValue;
}
```

Comment: Your code isn't valid. You're trying to return a list of some generic type (I'm guessing by the use of T) but the method doesn't list it as a generic parameter. Also, `fieldValue` is an IEnumerable but your method is prototyped to return a list.

Comment: From my understanding, T has to be a type, I do not believe that you can return anonymous. That said, I've never tried it, perhaps it is possible to return a List<object>?

Comment: @Sean wouldn't his thing still be IQueryable at that point? I don't see any calls to the db (namely with doing .ToList()) for it to turn into an IEnummerable, regardless your point about the return types is valid

Comment: What I am trying to return is a list, I have tried List of <Object> but that would not work also

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to return Anonymous Type from method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329672/is-there-a-way-to-return-anonymous-type-from-method)