# What is the Type of var in this case?

Tags: c#, types, reflection

I stumbled upon this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/5249859/13174465 about reflection in C#. My idea is to create a helper method out of it to use it in multiple places across my code. But I can't figure out what return type the method should have.
The IDE shows the type `local variable IEnumerable<{PropertyInfo Property, T Attribute}> properties` but this isn't accepted as return type of a method.

This is my current code which obviously doesn't work.

```
public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo, T> GetPropertiesAndAttributes<T>(object _instance, BindingFlags _bindingFlags = FULL_BINDING) where T : Attribute
    {
        var properties = from p in _instance.GetType().GetProperties(_bindingFlags)
            let attr = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), true)
            where attr.Length == 1
            select new { Property = p, Attribute = attr.First() as T};

        return properties;
    }
```

Which return type would be correct to make this method functional?

Thank you!

Comment: You can not return an anonymous type, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329672/is-there-a-way-to-return-anonymous-type-from-method.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware that anonymous types exist. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates an anonymous object:

```
new { Property = p, Attribute = attr.First() as T }
```

Anonymous types are generated by the compiler, so you can't declare a method that returns an anonymous type; they can exist in local scope only.

If you want to return the enumeration, you could use a ValueTuple as the item type instead:

```
public static IEnumerable<(PropertyInfo Property, T Attribute)> GetPropertiesAndAttributes<T>(
    object _instance, BindingFlags _bindingFlags = FULL_BINDING)
where T : Attribute
{
    var properties = from p in _instance.GetType().GetProperties(_bindingFlags)
        let attr = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), true)
        where attr.Length == 1
        select (Property: p, Attribute: attr.First() as T);

    return properties;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your current code you are trying to return *anonymous type*:

```
 new { Property = p, Attribute = attr.First() as T};
```

you can turn it into *named tuple* with a little change:

```
public static IEnumerable<(PropertyInfo p, T Attribute)> GetPropertiesAndAttributes<T>(
  object _instance, 
  BindingFlags _bindingFlags = FULL_BINDING) where T : Attribute
{
    var properties = from p in _instance.GetType().GetProperties(_bindingFlags)
        let attr = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), true)
        where attr.Length == 1
        select (p, attr.First() as T);

    return properties;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, this works!
I wasn't aware that anonymous types exist. Thank you!