# Want to return a list obtained in a linq query from a function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following snippet of code which fetches some data from a database and returns a list of records for which the structure is a custom defined in the query below:

```
var list = (from t in db.Transactions
    from tr in db.TransactionRules.Where(tr => EF.Functions.Like(t.Description, tr.Pattern)).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        t.TransactionId,
        t.Description,
        t.Note,
        t.Amount,
        t.Date,
        tr.Pattern,
        TransactionRuleId = tr.TransactionRuleId != null ? tr.TransactionRuleId : 0,
        TransactionRule = tr.TransactionRuleId != null ? tr : null,
        TransactionClass = tr.TransactionClass != null ? tr.TransactionClass : (t.TransactionClassId > 0 ? tc2 : new TransactionClass()),                                
        Final = t.Amount > 0 ? t.Amount : (tr.TransactionClass.Percentage > 0 ? (t.Amount / 100) * tr.TransactionClass.Percentage : t.Amount),
    });
```

I would like to move this to a class function, but I am not sure how to provide the type that the function should return:

```
public List GetTheList()
{
    var list = .../ etc
    return list;
}
```

I want to ideally do this without having to define a new type. Is it possible?

Comment: You cannot return a List of anonymous object, you should create a Dto that maps the properties selected in the query and return a list of this type.

Comment: It is not possible to return an anonymous type from a method, you can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1329672/9363973).

Comment: Thanks, I will define a dto in that case

Answer (score 1):

A ValueTuple is one way to avoid separately defining a return type, but it would be very unclean with your amount of properties in your final object.

```
public List<(string FirstName, string Surname, int Age)> GetStudents()
{
    var students = from s in db.Students
                   select (FirstName: s.Name, Surname: s.LastName, s.Age);

    return students.ToList();
}
```