# How can be possible to use anonymous type fields without know them?

Tags: c#, .net, anonymous-types

It is really looks so cool to me how GridView's DataSource property gets anonymous type  and shows results in Grid .

Simply

```
Grid.DataSource = from order in db.OrdersSet
       select new { order.PersonSet.Name,order.PersonSet.SurName};
```

For example how can i write a propery or method which takes anonymous type and write field values to console output ?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713521/accessing-c-anonymous-type-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reflection...

If you have an instance of an anonymous type, you can hold it in a variable of type `object`, call `GetType()` on it, and then `GetFields`, `GetProperties`, etc. to find out what columns are associated with it.  Each `PropertyInfo` or `FieldInfo` you see has the capability to retrieve the value from any instance of the type.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler actually creates (auto-generates) a class when it encounters syntax which use anonymous types, e.g.

```
var anonymousType = new { Name = "chibacity", Age = 21 };
```

This mechanism is automated by the compiler, but using a tool like [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/index.htm?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=unmet_need&utm_campaign=reflector&gclid=CNuUoYurnaICFY4U4wodZGsLxQ) you can disassemble the compiled code where you will see that a class has been generated to represent this anonymous type, e.g.:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
[DebuggerDisplay(@"\{ Name = {Name}, Age = {Age} }", Type="<Anonymous Type>")]
internal sealed class <>f__AnonymousType0<<Name>j__TPar, <Age>j__TPar>
{
    // Fields
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private readonly <Age>j__TPar <Age>i__Field;
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private readonly <Name>j__TPar <Name>i__Field;

    // Methods
    [DebuggerHidden]
    public <>f__AnonymousType0(<Name>j__TPar Name, <Age>j__TPar Age);
    [DebuggerHidden]
    public override bool Equals(object value);
    [DebuggerHidden]
    public override int GetHashCode();
    [DebuggerHidden]
    public override string ToString();

    // Properties
    public <Age>j__TPar Age { get; }
    public <Name>j__TPar Name { get; }
}
```

**Update**

Now that you have edited your question...

I am assuming that the question is that you desire to access the anonymous types outside of the scope it was declared in. This question is a duplicate of:

**Accessing C# Anonymous Type Objects**

[Accessing C# Anonymous Type Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713521/accessing-c-anonymous-type-objects)

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous types are syntactic sugar in a way. The compiler analyses the output of such operations and creates classes on the fly with the properties you request. It simply takes work from you - before anonymous types, you had to write classes or structs for every type you used, even though they were just temporary information. With anonymous classes/methods/lambdas you don't have to do this anymore and save a lot of time.

Comment: This is not answer of my question yet

Comment: Ah but that's because you edited your answer after @Femaref posted. It is customary on SO to add "Edited" to your question to make this clear. I have also answered whilst you edited.

Comment: Honestly i am thinking my question was clear but i have seen that answers was explain anonymous types so i tried to make my question more clear.If i would change question very differently.I would use edit

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var p = new { a = 10, b = 20 };

        TestMethod(p);
    }

    private void TestMethod(object p)
    {
        Type t = p.GetType();

        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in t.GetProperties())
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} = {1}", pi.Name, 
                t.InvokeMember(pi.Name, BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, p, null)));

        }
    }
```