# Unable to Print Anonymous type variable's values

Tags: c#, winforms

I have iterated

```
foreach (var tmp_variable in all_subdirectories)
{
    MessageBox.Show(tmp_variable["Name"]);
}
```

I want to print the **Name** inside **tmp_variable** .

In the Autos tab (While Debugging the variable value), the **tmp_variable** has the following values:
**tmp_variable  { Path = "D:\abc\folder1", Name = "folder1" }**

But unable to use any of such things.

I have tried writing

```
    MessageBox.Show(tmp_variable[Name]);
```

and,

```
    MessageBox.Show(tmp_variable.Name);
```

But nothing works. Everything shows error.

[image]

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of error messages (something to read: [Pictures of exceptions are not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Working with C# Anonymous Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935711/working-with-c-sharp-anonymous-types)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps.

```
var all_subdirectories = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(folderPath);

foreach (var tmp_variables in all_subdirectories)
{
    // Get the directory name only from filepath
    MessageBox.Show(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(tmp_variables));
}
```