# Retrieving Anonymous Type Collection Back From DataGrid.ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, anonymous-types

I'm writing a `collection of anonymous type` into WPF `DataGrid.ItemsSource`. And now I want it back. How do I do this, Is it possible?

How can I reconstruct the anonymous type?

Thanks!

### EDIT

Ok. So could You say will this work?

```
if(this.AbcDataGrid.ItemsSource != null && this.XyzDataGrid.ItemsSource != null)
{
    var abcdata = (IEnumerable<dynamic>)this.AbcDataGrid.ItemsSource;
    var xyzdata = (IEnumerable<dynamic>)this.XyzDataGrid.ItemsSource;

    var d1 = abcdata.ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.Id);
    var d2 = xyzdata.ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.Id);

    var result = from i1 in d1
                 from i2 in d2
                 select new
                 {
                     Name  = i1.Name,
                     Group = i1.Group.ToString() + i2.Group.ToString()
                 };
}
```

Properties `Group` and `Name` both present in anonymous type declaration.

Comment: I wouldn't do this. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713521/accessing-c-anonymous-type-objects

Comment: Sorry, but I just need it to be done. Example describes `casting by example` for single object. How do I gain similar result for collection?

Comment: The point is that anonymous types are type generated by the compiler, so when you want to get them back you don't "know" the type. They have to be treated as "objects" and hacked via reflection, or "dynamic" and read via "prayer".

Comment: Could you please be more consistant about `dynamic`. I can't get it.

Comment: Dynamic removes compile-time type safety, so you can declare a dynamic object as "dynamic d = DataSource.Items[ index ];", and it will compile fine, and you can even read/set properties (if they exist). The point is that you're "working around" compile-time type checking for no reason when you could just use a explicitly declared type.

Comment: @helicera, you have the code, why do you ask us whether it will work and not try it yourself?

Comment: I was worried about exceptions. I've tested the code it works fine. But I guess have a mistake in my own query so I got a lot of data duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options, but the best one is: don't do it. Anonymous types are meant to be used only in one function, not to store them somewhere and then retrieve them. Just create a normal class.

If you are sure you want to use anonymous type, you could use [cast by example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713521/accessing-c-anonymous-type-objects/713602#713602):

```
var anons = new[] { new { prop1 = 1, prop2 = "bar" }, new { prop1 = 42, prop2 = "foo" } };
IEnumerable casted = anons;
var castedBack = CastByExample(anons, new[] { new { prop1 = 0, prop2 = "" } });
```

Or you could use dynamic:

```
var d = (IEnumerable<dynamic>)casted;
```

Note that you *could* cast to `dynamic[]`, but doing so is not safe. Another option would be to cast to just `dynamic`, leaving type-safety completely.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to treat it as a `dynamic` type.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx

However, I would suggest you use a named class so that the producer and consumers can agree on the data.

Comment: Can you clarify how do I use dynamic logic here?

Comment: Do you mean the very first example? So should I use properties I specified in an. type like that non-existing methods in example? Will I gain the runtime exception?

Comment: Basically `foreach (dynamic item in DataGrid.ItemSource) { ... }`.