# Loop through datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I get the item data from wpf datagrid:

The item value is { ProductId = 1, Name = "fruit", Quantity = 1, Price = 100.0 } and the type is Anonymous Type.

Code:

```
foreach (var item in this.dgProductList.Items)
```

---

EDITED

This is how I add the row:

```
this.dgProductList.Items.Add(new { ProductId = product.ProductId, Name = product.Name, Quantity = 1, Price = product.Price });
```

Comment: Have you tried item.ProductId, item.Name, item.Quantity, item.Price? Without using wpf that just makes sense to me.

Comment: how do you bind your collection to the datagrid? can you post more code?

Comment: just bind your datagrids itemssource property to a Product Collection and do everything with this collection, querying, adding, deleting... It is so much easyier and cleaner and you dont' have to ask multiple questions on how to acces your items in the grid...

Answer (score 4):

Considering that you taged question with `WPF`, would say:

Do not act on `UI`. If you need to find something, find it on *Model* side. After, if you need  that `UI` in some way acts on founded item, act on `ModelView` to push `UI` changes on the screen.

In short: do not act on `UI` in `WPF`, as `UI` it easilly can become subject of change, and your code will break. Use the befints of powerfull data-binding `WPF` offers to you.

Comment: I am not using ItemsSource="{Binding}.

Comment: @KevFixx: well, that is actual point. It's better that you begin to use it. If you don't, just use *WindowsForms*.

Answer (score 0):

At first I must say I agree with Tigran, if you work with WPF, the suggested approach is to take advantage of databinding.

In your specific case you don't use databinding, you are adding anonymous types to a datagrid and then you want to retrieve them later.

At first I would suggest not to use anonymous types but instead create a class for Product.

Anyway if you want to continue to work with anonymous types you could apply the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272390/retrieving-anonymous-type-collection-back-from-datagrid-itemssource)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Like told you in the previous answers, you should consider using WPF-Binding.

But if you really dont want to, you can try this, but its not the "WPF-way":

```
object objectToFind = new { ProductId = 1, Name = "fruit", Quantity = 1, Price = 100.0 }; //create the object which should be found in your datagrid.

object result = dg.Items.Cast<object>().ToList().Find(o => o.Equals(objectToFind)); //find the object
```

Comment: Ok, I will try databinding, having hard time doing it.