# Writing to XML with anonymous types?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

Right now, I'm reading an XML document and pass its main elements to the method below. This method then returns the relevant elements in a IEnumerable, which is used to update a DataGridView.

```
private IEnumerable<object> readRelease(IEnumerable<XElement> release)
{
    return (
        from r in release
        select new
        {
            Release = r.Attribute("id").Value
            //etc.
        });
}
```

For the DataGridView, this method works well, but what if I want to write these elements to an XML file or, more broadly, just want to access a particular variable (e.g. "Release"). Can I then still use this method or should I go for something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing C# Anonymous Type Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713521/accessing-c-sharp-anonymous-type-objects)

Answer (score 2):

Kai is correct, however I'd like to point out that another option would be to use [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) instead of object if your c# compiler supports it. Then you can access properties and these will be resolved at the run-time. But as mentioned, in your scenario you most likely will be better off defining a new type.

Comment: For some reason I always feel dirty when using dynamic in a situation like this.

Answer (score 1):

There's another SO question about a dirty hack that allows you to access anonymous types outside a method but nobody would recommend using it:

[Accessing C# Anonymous Type Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713521/accessing-c-sharp-anonymous-type-objects)

If you need to access particular variables outside of the method it would probably be a better idea to define a new type instead of using an anonymous one.